# Hobby Project - Signal Frequency detector

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, filter, ultrasound, hobbyist

**Context:** I have taken on a little side hobby project to learn by making a circuit which should be able to only go high when it sense an acoustic signal with a frequency around 40kHz. To do this I will be connecting a microphone to a band pass filter and then hook it into an arduino which I am somehow going to programme to indicate when this happens:

---

### Main Idea

Microphone > Band pass filter > High voltage when 40k+ goes to Arduino to log this information.

---

For this whole project I will be using a battery so I will have **0 to +5** volts and so I cannot use -5v in any op amps.

For my **band pass filter** I have 2 options I can go really simple with something like a passive band pass filter:

[image]

Or I can go further and make an active bandpass filter: [ Although I do not understand how it works fully, I know that it is a higher order and is more precise and accurate :

[image]

The issue with this is the fact that the ADA4062-2 Op amp is extremely small. I would not be able to solder it or use it in a breadboard. Is there a way to find an op amp that could do this to avoid this issue?

For the Microphone/ultrasonic sensor I will be using this:

https://uk.farnell.com/camdenboss/ctd40k1007t/ultrasonic-transmitter-110db/dp/2610513

---

My questions:

1) Will using the simple passive band pass filter be enough.
2) Is there a way to find DIL integrated circuits to replace small surface mount ones?
3) In regards to the ultrasonic sensor can I just connect this to the band pass filter directly?

I am sorry for my lack of experience. I would appreciate any help.

Higher order circuit designed using: 
https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/

Comment: Have a look at this website, especially the "Infinite Gain Multiple Feedback Active Filter" section where you can see a band-pass filter with a high Q. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html

Comment: There are better ways to design active filters on TI’s webbench site.  1st define BW and gain then bandstop or order =4 so if you want 1% BW or 0.5% or whatever with high gain then it will tell you the GBW needed and tolerance if parts.    I would choose multiple feedback type rather than Salens & Keys then connect Vref to V/2 with cap.  Thus gives better R values at high Q.

Comment: That piezo microphone is a selective bandpass filter all on its own...you can likely benefit from a few high-pass RC filters to filter out audio. A few transistor amplifier stages should suffice to give a decent signal, since the Arduino AtoD is a high-impedance load. Start off simple.

Comment: @glen_geek
 The ultrasonic sensor itself is a band pass filter? how so?

Comment: This type sensor is a piezo-ceramic type, similar to a crystal, resonant at 40 kHz. It is quite sensitive at its resonant frequency, less so at other frequencies.

Comment: Paragraph D of the data sheet for your sensor has a curve of sensitivity versus frequency.  It shows that the 3 dB bandwidth is only about 1 kHz and drops rapidly after that.

Comment: 40 KHz is Ultrasonic, not audio, and beyond the near-ultrasonic where you can use audio parts.  Perhaps you should find an HC-SR04 ultrasonic ranger, and find the web page where someone reverse engineered it and figured out that the op-amp filter was mistuned and how to fix it.  Then look at the op-amp output upstream of the on-board MCU, perhaps if you like sample it with an ADC (even under sample it to downconvert...)